# obj/local/armeabi/objs/gnumake/*.d: No such file or directory

Tags: android, gcc, gdb

I have a rebuilt Android toolchain that support objc and I am trying to compile using ndk-build. In order to do this I have edited the definitions.mk and build-binary.mk in order to allow .m files. Everything seems good except when I try to compile I get...

```
jackie@jackie-Latitude-E6410:~/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source$ ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH="/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source" APP_BUILD_SCRIPT="/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/Android.mk" TARGET_CC="/home/jackie/Development/Google/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.1/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc" NDK_TOOLCHAIN="arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.1" EXTRA_EXTENSIONS=".m"
GNUMAKE: 
Compile thumb  : gnumake <= NSXMLDTDNode.m
cc1obj: fatal error: /home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/obj/local/armeabi/objs/gnumake//NSXMLDTDNode.d: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/jackie/Development/Code/GnuStep/core/base/Source/obj/local/armeabi/objs/gnumake//NSXMLDTDNode.o] Error 1
```

Any ideas? Is there something else I have to do to add objective c support to GDB?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I needed to remove the following from definitions.mk

-MMD -MP -MF $$(call convert-deps,$$(PRIVATE_DEPS))

That seems to allow it to work and not create debugging symbols. I would prefer less of a hack.